# Не работает PageSpeed

Tags: битрикс, pagespeed-insights, pagespeed

При попытке проверить скорость загрузки сайта вылетает ошибка

> Lighthouse returned error: PROTOCOL_TIMEOUT. Истекло время ожидания
> ответа от протокола DevTools. Метод: Runtime.evaluate.
> (PROTOCOL_TIMEOUT)

Сайт пишу на Bitrix[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не понимаю в чем проблема, в логах сервера ничего не нашел.
Самое интересное что вчера вечером все работало, а сегодня вдруг перестало, хотя я ничего и не менял

Comment: Там может быть много причин включая проблемы с соединением. Попробуйте указать в вашем вопросе УРЛ затронутый этой проблемой.

Comment: @nikant25, забыл отписаться, проблема решилась сама собой на следующее утро... В чем заключалась проблема я так и не понял

Comment: проблема решилась сама собой на следующее утро